# Looking for books etc on gender animacy in Oromo

Tags: reference-request, gender, morphosyntax, animacy

I request you if you are willing and able to help me on my linguistics thesis with the title of ***The morphosyntax of gender animacy and clitics in Oromo***.

Oromo is one of the Cushitic branch languages which is spoken by more than 35 million people in Ethiopia, Kenya, Somalia, Djibouti and other areas.

Therefore I appreciate anyone  who will provide me information and suggest me some references (books) related with my topics.

Comment: Welcome to the site @Leta_Tesfa. I'm afraid that i've downvoted your question, as we expect people to do at least some minimal research before asking a question on linguistics SE. Please give us the details of some concrete problem you are struggling with, and try not to make it quite so obvious that you're looking for help with uni work.

Comment: Personally I think asking for uni work is fine, as long as (and here I agree completely with P Elliott) you show you invested some time in solving the question yourself and it's a concrete problem.

Comment: I've reworded your question to focus on the search for books on your topic. If you find particular points in the field as you work on it you are welcome to ask focussed questions along the way.